# Mysql database - primary key problem

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: let say table 1 (userid, username, password) and table 2 (userid, a, b, c).

table 1 has a userid field (primary key), table 2 also has userid (references table 1).

If I do an insert statement, to add a row to table 2, how does table 2 generate the userid field?

Edit:
**I want to insert things into table 2 where the userid in table 2 MUST match userid in table 1 - what constraints do I need to set up**

Comment: you have to assign table 2 the userid to reference table 1, but you most likely want to have unique primary id for table 2 itself. so, you'll have (tableid, userid, a, b, c)

Answer (score 1):

The database doesn't understand the relationship between `table1` and `table2` unless you explicitly specify it.  You can use [SQL foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) if you are using a database engine the supports them (InnoDB).

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    userid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE table2 (
    rowid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    userid INTEGER NOT NULL
        REFERENCES table1(userid)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    -- other columns here
);
```

The `REFERENCES` option will tell the database engine that `table2.userid` requires that a row exist in `table1` such that `table1.userid = table2.userid`.   The `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` clauses will cause the deletion of a row in `table1` to automatically delete/update rows in `table2`.

You cannot create a row in `table2` until you have created a row for the user in `table1`.  The row in `table1` will auto-generate the `userid`.  When you insert into `table2`, you will explicitly include the user id from `table1` to establish the linkage between the rows.

Comment: I believe that is what I have set up - table 2 userid references table1 userid - but I get this error when doing the insert statement, Second: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'UserID' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 0):

If the userid field on table2 is not autoincrement then *you* have to provide the value or the insert will fail.

Comment: ok so if I add auto increment to userid in table 2, it will change the field to according what is in table 1's userid?

Comment: No, it will generate a brand new id - you need to provide an id from table1 yourself

Comment: Ok my idea doesn't work. :P Let's clarify things again.

I want to insert things into table 2 where the userid in table 2 MUST match userid in table 1 - what constraints do I need to set up/

Comment: UserId in table to must have a foreign key constraint to userid from table 1, and inside INSERT statement for table 2 you need to provide the value of UserId from table 1.

Comment: How can i get the userid of the user that is logged in, from table 1 to pass into table 2? On my site, the user has to login to submit data (which goes to table 2).

Comment: Do not ask me that - how possibly I can know how to get a logged on user in your application? I haven't seen your code, have I? - Do you know how to get a logged in user in *my* application?

Answer (score 0):

If username and password is not null then don't insert in tabel 1 and give error

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined userID in table2 as **foriegn key constraint**, then you will need to have the corresponding userID in the table1 as reference when inserting rows to table2, else if you have not defined any such constraints, then it will not matter.

Keep in mind, if the constraint is defined, then table2 will not generate ID by itself. It would require the ID to be present in the table1 column which is referenced.